# Connecting to 192.168.1.63:1337 ftp

Tags: windows-10, ftp, playstation

So I am connecting to a local ftp using `ftp://192.168.1.63:1337` now that I have connected I can see the files and directorys. I can't figure out how to upload files to it. Windows 10 connecting to a PSvita via henkaku Ideas?

Comment: I'm neither psychic or a mind reader. What is your Operating System? What program are you using for ftp? Please [edit] the question and include this essential information.

Comment: I use FireFTP in Firefox - drag and drop

Comment: I assume you're connecting in a browser, and browsers do what they say: they browse - they don't do file management, though they nearly all allow down-loads. Many have plug-ins to allow full FTP up/down-loads - FireFTP for FireFox is one of the best. Windows explorer and the Linux file manager will also connect to an FTP site and allow copying to and from the site using the normal file management functions. Otherwise, there are lots of stand-alone FTP clients, including `ftp`, which is the standard command-line program. (Crossed with @DavidPostill, yet again!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) if you wish to upload files on hosting server or local server.

There is another way use php file upload script.but if you are in local then why you want to upload from browser??
Here is demo [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: I have to (Using henkaku with a PS vita)